# Braintree Swift keep printing html in generated token

Tags: swift, braintree

Im trying to generate a token in brain tree, for some reason its generating the entire html which is causing the the token to be invalid how can this be resolve. this is my current function

```
func brainTree() {

        let clientTokenURL = NSURL(string: "http://mywesitelinkhere.com/braintree_php_api/public_html/index.php/client_token")!


        let clientTokenRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: clientTokenURL)


        clientTokenRequest.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(clientTokenRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in



            print("data start- \(data) -data end")

            print("response start- \(response) -response end")

            print("Error is \(error?.localizedDescription)")


            let clientToken = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            print("token is\(clientToken) token end")

            self.braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: clientToken)
            // As an example, you may wish to present our Drop-in UI at this point.
            // Continue to the next section to learn more...
        }.resume()


    }
```

this is token being print

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BraintreePHPExample</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css/app.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css/overrides.css">
    <script src="javascript/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/vendor/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/demo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <header class="main">
    <div class="container wide">
        <div class="content slim">
            <div class="set">
                <div class="fill">
                    <a class="pseudoshop" href="/">PSEUDO<strong>SHOP</strong></a>
                </div>

                <div class="fit">
                    <a class="braintree" href="https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in" target="_blank">Braintree</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="notice-wrapper">
            </div>
</header>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="checkout container">

            <header>
                <h1>Hi, <br>Let's test a transaction</h1>
                <p>
                    Make a test payment with Braintree using PayPal or a card
                </p>
            </header>

            <form method="post" id="payment-form" action="/braintree_php_api/public_html/checkout.php">
                <section>
                    <div class="bt-drop-in-wrapper">
                        <div id="bt-dropin"></div>
                    </div>

                    <label for="amount">
                        <span class="input-label">Amount</span>
                        <div class="input-wrapper amount-wrapper">
                            <input id="amount" name="amount" type="tel" min="1" placeholder="Amount" value="10">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </section>

                <button class="button" type="submit"><span>Test Transaction</span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
    <script>
        var checkout = new Demo({
            formID: 'payment-form'
        })
        var client_token = "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";

        braintree.setup(client_token, "dropin", {
            container: "bt-dropin"
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The issue is with your server-side code, not anything in swift. The problem is that your website needs to serve up only the token and not HTML. You can test this on a Mac/*nix system with `curl`:

```
curl http://mywesitelinkhere.com/braintree_php_api/public_html/index.php/client_token
```

​
If this command returns anything other than just the client token string then you need to fix your server. The [Braintree getting started guide's client token generation lines](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php#send-a-client-token-to-your-client) are really all you need:

```
<?php
  Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
  Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('use_your_merchant_id');
  Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('use_your_public_key');
  Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('use_your_private_key');

  echo($clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate());
?>
```

Take a look at your server code and strip out everything except the printing of this string from that url.